# Indicate the presence of an image in the Tools > Flags tab

Tags: feature-request, flagging, 10k-tools

In the Tools > Flags tab of the 10k tools, all images are **silently** suppressed:

[image]

For some posts (particularly proofs-by-picture and containing scans), this can easily lead to wrong flags.

So please include at least *some* indication that there's an image in the question, and do not silently suppress it. I can understand the reasoning behind not showing images in this tab, but the current practice compromises the ability to review properly.

Comment: Related: What is the right action for this post? It is flagged as a "duplicate answer". I agree with this, but what should be done? The flagging reason "Duplicate answer" is not available to me, and all the other reasons clearly don't fit.

Comment: When I checked, the answer it was an alleged duplicate of was deleted, so nothing needed to be done. In case of actual duplication, commenting and custom flags seem the way to go.

Comment: It’s a perfectly reasonable request, but I don’t think that it’s actually possible to review *properly* without looking at the actual question page.